# How do you interpret the 3rd condition? Is $g'(x)$ always non zero except for $a$ or is $g'(x)$ not always $0$?

Tags: real-analysis

In Jon Rogawski's Calculus early Transcendentals, the L'hopital's rule is stated as the follow:

> Let f, g be real valued function with one real variable.
>
> If
>
> (1)f,g differentialbe on an open interval containing a
>
> (2)f(a)=g(b)=0,
>
> (3)$g'(x)\neq 0$(execpt possibly at a)
>
> then $\lim_{x\to a}\frac {f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim_{x\to a}\frac {f'(x)}{g'(x)}$

My question is: How do you interpret the 3rd condition? Is $g'(x)$ always non zero except for $a$ or is $g'(x)$ not always $0$?

Comment: The third condition asks that $\forall x \neq a, g'(x) \neq 0$

Comment: It need not be globally non-zero, just on that open interval containing $a$.

Comment: Shouldn't (2) say $f(a)=g(a)=0$?